# Asset Browser - Link and Append Object and Snapping behave differently

Tags: asset-browser

I'm playing with the asset browser lately and i realized that you cannot snap a Linked file but you can with an Append File.

Is this supposed to be liked that or maybe it's a bug and i need to report it ?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

So I reported this bug and for now they **are not going to support the snap** for **linked assets** :

1.[I reported it here](https://developer.blender.org/T95691)

2.[They send me the unsolved task here](https://developer.blender.org/rBf81c514bd22a25b2c6951e506f64252e0f5e84bf)

Comment: This is really unfortunate and I hope this changes.  I can't see the use of linking if you cannot accurately place and rotate linked meshes.  In Archviz for example we constantly have to assemble scenes with multiple buildings from different sources not all having the same coordinate system.  These buildings obviously need to be snapped to some location in the master file and rotated.  If we cannot do so in Blender the software simply cannot be used very widely for this purpose.

Comment: According to the commit: `The location of a linked object isn't editable, or at least it will be reset when reloading the file.` I don't know what these people are smoking, but for me the position and rotation are both preserved even after a full restart. Not only that, but the location and rotation is preserved *even if I edit the original asset*.